# What impact does the ancestor file have with git merge-file?

Tags: git

Consider this example command line session...

```
$ git --version
git version 2.19.0.windows.1    
$ echo "header" > ancestor.txt
$ cp ancestor.txt left.txt
$ cp ancestor.txt right.txt
```

At this point, I've made an ancestor file and started two "branches". Now I'll make a change to each one.

```
$ echo "on the left" >> left.txt
$ echo "on the right" >> right.txt
```

And another, with coincidentally identical lines.

```
$ echo "footer" >> left.txt
$ echo "footer" >> right.txt
```

Now I want to merge my two branches together using [git merge-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9122948/3568).

```
$ git merge-file --union left.txt ancestor.txt right.txt
$ cat left.txt
header
on the left
on the right
footer
```

There is only one "footer" line in the merge output. My expectation is that because each branch file has footer separately and the ancestor doesn't, I should get two "footer" lines in the merge, one from the left and one from the right. (I am only expecting one "header", because it is in the ancestor.)

If I repeat the experiment up to the git call, but replacing ancestor.txt with an empty file, I get exactly the same output. Even if I fill ancestor.txt with junk, I still get the same output.

Am I doing this wrong? Have I found a bug in git? Is the ancestor file redundant? What's going on?

Comment: Dear voters-to-close, is there a better SE site for this type of question please?